# After a date is selected from slicer on page 1, the slicer on page 2 is set to "the date + 1 month"

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a report that has two pages. One page 1, when a user picks a date period from the slicer, say "July 2018" (see the 1st screenshot), The default date on page 2 will have to be "the date + 1 month (August 2018) (see the 2nd screenshot).

Is this requirement doable? Thank you all for the help.

[image]
[image]